# How to make API calls to AWS Managed Blockchain using Nethereum?

Tags: nethereum, aws

I am testing AWS Ethereum (Preview) using Nethereum and I see this method to get a block:

```
var block = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockNumber.SendRequestAsync();
```

However, the AWS Ehtereum documentation says:

> Ethereum on Managed Blockchain (Preview) only supports the
> eth_sendRawTransaction method, which requires that you create and sign
> the transaction before sending it to the node.

I believe to sign the transaction with Nethereum, you do this:

```
var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
var encoded = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign(msg1, new EthECKey(privateKey));
var txId = await web3.Eth.Transactions.SendRawTransaction.SendRequestAsync("0x" + encoded);
```

So my question is, how would I call the "GetBlockNumber" while signing the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the team at Nethereum, they provided a solution for me. The link below is for making API calls to AWS Managed Blockchain, in case anyone else needs it.

> All Ethereum JSON-RPC API calls to an Ethereum node on Managed
> Blockchain are authenticated using the Signature Version 4 signing
> process. This means that only authorized IAM principals in the AWS
> account that created the node can interact with it using the API. AWS
> credentials (an access key ID and secret access key) must be provided
> with the call.

https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.AWS/